# On Mac OS X, how to create multi-touch event and send to another application?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, osx-snow-leopard, macos-carbon

I want to "simulate" a multi-touch event for another application, e.g., simulate a zoom-in gesture on iPhoto. I searched many sources but can't find an answer for that.

It seems the most common way to sending an event to other application is with script bridge, getting a SBApplication and then send an AppleEvent. But it seems the general gesture or multi touch events are not there for common applications.

Also, there is no function like CGEventCreateMultiTouchEvent...(), thus I don't know if it's achievable by CGEventPost()

The method NSApplication.sendEvent might be able send a NSEvent which has the multi touch type defined. But how could I get the NSApplication* of another application?

Any help will be very appreciated :)

Comment: Apple Events are high-level events like “do that thing to that thing”, not low-level events like “click/touch there”.

Comment: Just an idea, can you create the NSEvent then invoke the CGEvent method to get a CGEventRef to use with CGEventPost()?

Answer (score 1):

I would script the application directly.  I'd use "plain" objective-c.